# Using return statement in switch expression

Tags: c#

```cs
var chose = 2;

string message = chose switch
{
   1 => return 2,
   2 => "hello",
   3 => "wow",
   _ => "default".
};
```

In this case, the function returns an `Integer` and `message` is just a string variable used after this switch to obtain an Integer.
Is there a way to use the `return` statement inside of a case of this switch expression?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for the full `switch` syntax instead of a `switch` *expression*?

Comment: Yes i know i can do it with a normal switch syntax, but i'm wondering if it is possible with the switch espression version

Comment: I wouldn't expect so (though I could be wrong), because in this case the compiler can't guarantee that the expression will resolve to a `string`.

Comment: The entire point of a switch *expression* is to use expression syntax, which doesn't allow complex statements, so return is not possible. You can't even use switch expressions without a return type, i.e. *void*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is C# now has two different ways to use the `switch` keyword.

One of those is a traditional switch block, which allows you to include any arbitrary code.

The other is the newer switch **expression**. The newer expression syntax is not a traditional switch block, but rather a single expression, and therefore must follow all the rules of any expression, including ensuring there is a result that conforms to type safety.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't return from inside a switch expression, but instead, you can do something similar to this:

```cs
int chose = 2;

string? message = chose switch
{
    1 => null,
    2 => "hello",
    3 => "wow",
    _ => "default"
};
if (message is null) return 2;
```

Here if `chose` is 2, I'm setting `message` to `null` and returning if it *is* null, otherwise the rest of your code can continue.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you return a tuple of `int? id` and `string? message`, you can write it like this

```
public (int? id, string? message) GetChosen(int chose)
    => chose switch
    {
        1 => (2, null),
        2 => (null, "hello"),
        3 => (null, "wow"),
        _ => (null, "default")
    };
```

Which works similarly to this, using a return object (record)

```
public ChosenOne GetChosenOne(int chose)
{
    return chose switch
    {
        1 => new ChosenOne(2, null),
        2 => new ChosenOne(null, "hello"),
        3 => new ChosenOne(null, "wow"),
        _ => new ChosenOne(null, "default")
    };
}

public record ChosenOne(int? Id, string? Message);
```